# Existence function $f$ which isn't uniform continuity, but $f^2$ is?

Tags: general-topology

Existence function $f$ which isn't uniform continuity, but $f^2$ is? I don't have more asumptions about function $f$, so let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X,Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with euclidean metrice.

In my opinion if $f^2$ is uniform continuity then we have $$\forall \varepsilon > 0  \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \forall x,y \in X \quad |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f^2(x) - f^2(y)| < \varepsilon $$

From the last inequality we have that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{|f(x)+f(y)|}$. So can I now conclude that $f$ is uniform continuity? What can I say about $|f(x)+f(y)|$ ? The problem for me is that, if $|f(x)+f(y)| \rightarrow 0$ then  $\frac{\varepsilon}{|f(x)+f(y)|} \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: $f=2\mathbf 1_\mathbb Q-1$.

Comment: What is $21_{\mathbb{Q}}$ ?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$, $f(x)=-1$ if $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your example: $f$ is not continuity so is not uniform continuity, but $f^2 \equiv 1 $ of course is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: since $f$ itself does not have to be continuous, think about a function $f$ which is not continuous, so that $f^2$ is constant.

Comment: I really can not imagine such function (even sketch).

Comment: Indirect hint: What are the solutions of $x^2=1$?

Comment: Of course $x=1$ and $x=-1$ so we can take function such that $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in A$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $x \in X \setminus A$. Of course $f^2 \equiv 1$ for $x \in X$.